# Collecting XML child nodes from multiple parent nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I am performing some web scraping of tide times for a personal program I am writing. The user enters a port/location code and it downloads the HTML web page containing tide times in table format for the next seven days from the UKHO for that specific port. Then the program removes all the HTML code before and after the tables to leave seven tables containing tide data. It then turns the HTML into a valid XML file. This is currently the XML the program creates for a port:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tides portID="0547" port="St. Ives">
  <Day>
    <tr>
      <th>Sat 13 Jun</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>HW</th>
      <th>LW</th>
      <th>HW</th>
      <th>LW</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02:00</td>
      <td>08:35</td>
      <td>14:30</td>
      <td>21:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5.9m</td>
      <td>1.4m</td>
      <td>5.9m</td>
      <td>1.4m</td>
    </tr>
  </Day>
  <Day>
    <tr>
      <th>Wed 17 Jun</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>HW</th>
      <th>LW</th>
      <th>HW</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>05:17</td>
      <td>11:40</td>
      <td>17:34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6.4m</td>
      <td>1.0m</td>
      <td>6.5m</td>
    </tr>
  </Day>
  <Day>
    <tr>
      <th>Sun 14 Jun</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>HW</th>
      <th>LW</th>
      <th>HW</th>
      <th>LW</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02:57</td>
      <td>09:29</td>
      <td>15:23</td>
      <td>21:56</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6.1m</td>
      <td>1.2m</td>
      <td>6.1m</td>
      <td>1.2m</td>
    </tr>
  </Day>
</Tides>
```

However I need to transform it into a format like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tides portID="0547" port="St. Ives">
  <Day date="Sat 13 Jun">
    <Tides>
      <Tide type="HW" time="02:00" height="5.9m"/>
      <Tide type="LW" time="08:35" height="1.4m"/>
      <Tide type="HW" time="14:30" height="5.9m"/>
      <Tide type="LW" time="21:05" height="1.4m"/>
    </Tides>
  </Day>
  <Day date="Wed 17 Jun">
    <Tides>
      <Tide type="HW" time="05:17" height="6.4m"/>
      <Tide type="LW" time="11:40" height="1.0m"/>
      <Tide type="HW" time="17:34" height="6.5m"/>
    </Tides>
  </Day>
  <Day date="Sun 14 Jun">
    <Tides>
      <Tide type="HW" time="02:57" height="6.1m"/>
      <Tide type="LW" time="09:29" height="1.2m"/>
      <Tide type="HW" time="15:23" height="6.1m"/>
      <Tide type="LW" time="21:56" height="1.2m"/>
    </Tides>
  </Day>
</Tides>
```

I do not know where to start to transfer it to a format like that, mainly because the code is in rows and not columns (ie, each  tag contains columns not rows) so I would have to somehow count up and on each iteration get a node from each  tag and add it to a single node in the new format but I cannot figure out how to do this. Making it harder is the fact that one day can contain either 4,3 or 2 tides (shown as the second  tag in the samples).

I need it in the new format so it is a smaller file and easier to read. How can I get the XML in the first format into the format of the second XML sample using C#? Thanks for any help you can give me, I just can't work out how to collect the child HW/LW, times and heights into collections containing one of each and put them into new nodes.

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT for something like this?  It's designed to do exactly that - take one XML file and translate into a different format (XML or HTML, usually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a code writing service, however I seem to be feeling a little generous.  You want to parse using LINQ to XML and then transform the data across to your required format.  This code doesn't handle any issues in the source file (for example, if each `<tr>` contained a different number of `<td>` values),  but it works for your sample:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (var day in doc.Descendants("Day"))
{
    var rows = day.Elements("tr").ToList();

    rows.Remove();

    var date = (string)rows[0].Element("th");

    day.Add(new XAttribute("date", date));

    var tides = new XElement("Tides");

    var types = rows[1].Elements().Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();
    var times = rows[2].Elements().Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();
    var heights = rows[3].Elements().Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();

    for (var i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
    {
        tides.Add(new XElement("Tide",
            new XAttribute("type", types[i]),
            new XAttribute("time", times[i]),
            new XAttribute("height", heights[i])
            ));
    }

    day.Add(tides);
}

var result = doc.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. Also that error you mentioned will not be a problem as I was going to say in the question (but couldn't find the words) that each <td> will always have the same number as each tide has a time, type and height. Thanks again